# Highcharts Donut chart is rendered as a Pie chart in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, charts, highcharts

I'm using latest version of Highcharts library. Overall library seem to be pretty cool, however I faced with quite annoying issue: donut chart is not rendered correctly in IE 8 when there is only one option to render.

```
            var chart;
        var data = [['There could be only one', 1444]];
        var containerId = 'container';
        var chartTitle = 'Equity';

        $(document).ready(function () {
Highcharts.theme = {
   colors: ["#1987c9", "#7fba00", "#f4911e", "#006D75", "#542344", "#f7403a"]
}

var highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: containerId,
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    legend:{
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        layout: 'vertical',
        width: 170,
        itemStyle: {
            fontSize: '13px'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: chartTitle,
        style: {
            fontSize: '17px'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} <b>{point.y}</b>',
        percentageDecimals: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.name +': '+ this.point.y.toLocaleString();
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px'
                }
            },
            innerSize: '40%',
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: chartTitle,
        data: data
    }],
    exporting: {
        enabled:false
    }
});
```

});

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/olanet/whZnP/2/

JSFiddle result (enable IE 8 Compatibility or use IE 8): http://fiddle.jshell.net/olanet/whZnP/2/show/

[image: Chart in IE 8]

[image: Chart in IE 9]

Comment: Looks like an issue with Highcharts plugin in IE8. In order to make the donout chart work properly in IE8 at least there should be two non-zero values. For e.g. data = [['There could be only one', 1444], ['the second value',1]]

Comment: Well, it looks like an obvious way to go, but it doesn't fix the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/olanet/9CRaP/19/. And also legend looks broken in IE after that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem exists only when arc is rendered completely. If we remove a small part of this arc than problem disappears. To fix the issue:
1. Find following line in source:
`end = mathRound((startAngleRad + (cumulative * circ)) * precision) / precision;`
2. Add following code after it:

```
if (len == 1) {
    end -= 0.001;
}
```

3. That would add a small gap in a circle but the end result would look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, so I've reported it https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1642